# How to tackle with multiple time product load in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, optimization

I am working in customized site that site have ***used the product model load within loop multiple times***.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Any Quick Fix that I can use with override the load method and keep minimum php resources and make it better for more concurrent users.

Comment: Please provide that code

Comment: A solution cannot be provided from just one line of code. Please provide the entire block of code.

Comment: And there really is no 'one solution fits all' if this is done in multiple instances. Each will need to be analyzed, figure out what its up to, and be corrected, within the scope of each routine. If they are all the same, identical code blocks, you got bigger problems....

Answer (score 2):

In general the colleagues are right. But in this specific example you can try to use directly collection. Instead of:

```
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
}
```

use something like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //do something
}
```